# How to set fixed height of flex block?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

I need table with:

1. Scroll on tbody and fixed height of thead
2. 100% height of page
3. Some div header with fixed width

All works apart 3d point. The height of header depends on tr count and page height. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6806/

[image: a busy cat]

Code (see Fiddle for full code):

```
.container1 {
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:column;
}

.subdiv1 {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.scrolltable {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:column;

}
```

Html:

```
<div class="panel panel-danger container1">
    <div class="panel-heading subdiv1">
        ->> How can I make fixed height of this div? <<--
    </div>  

    <table class="scrolltable">
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you aware it doesn't work at all in FireFox?

Comment: yes, really, you are right. Interesting, where is my mistake.